# How many five-digit numbers are there that have number 4 as at least one digit?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

How many five-digit numbers are there that have number 4 as at least one digit?

How to do this? I don't know how to start.

Comment: How many five-digit numbers are there that don't have number 4 as digit at all?

Answer (score 3):

There are $9\cdot10^4$ five-digit numbers, since there are $9$ choices for the first digit, and $10$ choices for the next $4$ digits.

Of these numbers, $8\cdot 9^4$ do not contain $4$ as a digit. Therefore the number of $5$-digit numbers with at least one $4$ as a digit is equal to
$$ 9\cdot 10^4-8\cdot 9^4=37512$$

Answer (score 2):

The easiest is to just subtract all of the ones that don't:

1 digit numbers: 8 possibilities (1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9)

2 digit numbers: 8 possibilities for the first * 9 possibilities for the second (0,1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9) = 72

3 digit numbers: 8 possibilities for the first * 9 possibilities for the second (0,1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9) * 9 possibilities for the third (0,1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9) = 648

etc...

Comment: $4$ digit numbers: $8\times 9^3= 5832$, $5$ digit numbers: $8\times 9^4= 5832\times 9 = 52488$. Sum of all: $8+72+648+5832+52488= 728+5832+52488= 6560 + 52488= 59048$. But, $90000-59048 =   30952 $, which does not match with the other answer.

Comment: # single digit no.: $8: \,\,(1-3, 5-59)$. Next are two digit numbers: $8$ choices for msb $1-3,\,\, 5-9)\times 9$ choices for lsb ($0-3,\,\, 5-9$). But, # of two digit numbers $=72$, not excludes both single digit ($=1: \{4\}$) & double digit numbers ($=18:  \{14, 24, 34, 54, 64, 74, 84, 94, 40 \cdots 49\}$). This can be seen by taking difference from all possible two & one digit numbers ($10\times 10 -1= 99$), of above ($19= 1+18$) two digit numbers, as get $99-19=80 \ne 72$. Need add $8$ single digit numbers to get $80-8=72$. So, the selected answer of  $90000-52488 = 37512$ is wrong.